# JavaScript regex for custom validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for validating a string / decimal in JavaScript.

Which can be max 9 elements long with 2 decimals

Simply

```
123 - valid
123456789 - valid
1234567896 - invalid ( max 10 chars )

123. - invalid
123.2 - valid
123.32 valid
123.324 invalid ( 3 decimal points )
```

So I wrote a regexp like this

```
/^([0-9]{1,9})+[.]+([0-9]{0,2})$/
```

Can any one plz fine tune this regex

Comment: So `12345678.12` should be invalid?

Comment: what about leading zeros? is 0123 valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `^(?=.{0,10}$)\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).css('color', this.value.match(/^(?=.{0,10}$)\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,2})?$/) ? 'green' : 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text/>
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/zZ2lH0/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: The max number of characters this regex allows is 12. It should be 9.

Answer (score 2):

Give the following a try:

```
^\d{1,9}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: The max number of characters this regex allows is 12. It should be 9.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
/^[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/
```

Comment: The max number of characters this regex allows is 12. It should be 9.

Comment: Did you interpret the question like that? I thought he meant it can be 9 characters long plus two decimals.

Comment: **`Which can be max 9 elements long with 2 decimals`**

Answer (score 1):

You may use a negative lookahead at the beginning to apply a length restriction *to the **whole** match*:

```
^(?!\S{10})\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ5pI1/1)

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\S{10})` - no more than 9 non-whitespace characters from the beginning to end condition
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - 1 or zero groups of `.` + 1 or w2 digits
- `$` - end of string

However, you might as well just match the float/integer numbers with `^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` and then check the length of the matched text to decide whether it is valid or not.

Note that in case you have to omit leading zeros, you need to get rid of them first:

```
s = s.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

And then use the regex above.